# Can't get Android App to Exit

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm struggling to get my android app to exit via the alertdialog.

Clicking 'yes' to play again works fine as in it restarts the app and you get to go again.

Unfortunately, when I click 'no' it just removes the dialog alert box and I can't figure out why.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
@Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           AlertDialog.Builder alert = new    AlertDialog.Builder(Task1Activity.this);
           alert.setMessage("You have guessed incorrectly three times. " +
               "The answer was " + ranNum + ". " + "Would you like to play again?")
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Task1Activity.this, Task1Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);

    }
});

alert
.setCancelable(false)
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
Task1Activity.this.finish();
};
)
    .setTitle("Unlucky!")
    .create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating the Activity `Intent i = new Intent(Task1Activity.this, Task1Activity.class);` which added the activity on stack.

try this code:

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        Task1Activity.this);
alertDialog.setTitle("Unlucky!");
alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
alertDialog.setMessage("You have guessed incorrectly three times. " +
           "The answer was " + ranNum + ". " + "Would you like to play again?");
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)        {
                 Intent i = new Intent(Task1Activity.this, Task1Activity.class);
                 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();   
                //getActivity().finish();
                finishAffinity();   //finish all previous activity on stack
            }
        });
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I tried it exactly like this and the 'no' option works in that it closes the app.  The only problem is that now the 'yes' option isn't even available any more.  Any ideas?

Comment: when u press yes button what happens?

Comment: Forget that.  I forgot to change the 'no' button to a negative one.  It works great.  Thanks

Comment: The yes button restarts the app which is what I wanted it to do.  If I'm being picky the 'no' comes before the 'yes' (left to right) but I'll take that as long as they do what I want them to do

Answer (score 0):

You keep adding activities on top of each other every time you do:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Task1Activity.this, Task1Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

In order to keep only 1 activity alive you should `finish()` the old one when you start a new activity:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Task1Activity.this, Task1Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is `startActivity(i);` 
When you click on the ok, `startActivity(i)` starts another `Task1Activity` on current `Task1Activity` and when you press the cancel, the top `Task1Activity` is finishing and you go back the previous  `Task1Activity`.
Try `startActivity(i)` with flag.

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```